Map<?, Optional<T>> to Map<?, T>
I have a Map with Optional values.
I want to filter it to remove empty values.
Map<K, Optional<T>> input;

Map<K, T> result = input.
// here is some code I'm looking for
                   .collect(Collector.toMap(???));

What is easiest way to achieve it?
All I can think of requires Optional.get and I don't like that IDE warns me about it.

not sure which warning you are getting, but have you tried using orElseThrow() ? (documentation  of get(): "API Note:
The preferred alternative to this method is orElseThrow().")

I was wrong about warning. After I filtered by isPresent warning disappeared. My IDE smarter than me :)

The easiest way to do it, especially while avoiding Optional.get(), isn't going to involve streams at all; more like
Map<K, T> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
input.forEach((k, vOpt) -> {
  vOpt.ifPresent(v -> result.put(k, v));
});

(In general, if there isn't a really obvious way to do something with streams, it's generally going to be simpler and cleaner not to use streams at all.)
If you insist on using a Collector, it's possible but requires a carefully customized one, especially if you won't tolerate Optional.get().
map.entrySet().stream()
  .collect(Collector.of(
    LinkedHashMap::new,
    (map, entry) -> entry.getValue().ifPresent(v -> map.put(entry.getKey(), v)),
    (m1, m2) -> { 
      m1.putAll(m2);
      return m1;
    }));

If you can tolerate Optional.get(), you might consider it simpler to write
map.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().get()));


One way is by using Stream.mapMulti (available since Java 16):
Map<K, T> result = input.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .<Map.Entry<K, T>> mapMulti((x, c) -> {
        if (x.getValue().isPresent()) {
            c.accept(Map.entry(x.getKey(), x.getValue().get()));
        }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

This allows an imperative approach.
Here's a more functionalish way that does exactly the same:
Map<K, T> result = input.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .<Map.Entry<K, T>> mapMulti((x, c) -> x.getValue()
                .ifPresent(v -> c.accept(Map.entry(x.getKey(), v))))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

The code above uses Optional.ifPresent.
Another way is by using Collectors.filtering:
Map<K, T> result = input.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.filtering(
                x -> x.getValue().isPresent(),
                Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, x -> x.getValue().get())));

(Note: my IntelliJ produces a warning on Optional.get(), but this warning is wrong).
